# Does the Ramacharitamanas Prashnavali concept have any basis in Scriptures?

Tags: scripture, rama, ramcharitmanas

[**The Ramacharitamanas Prashnavali or Sri Ramashalaka Prashnavali**](http://www.astrospeak.com/prashnavali)

> The answers/predictions in Ramacharitamanas Prashnavali or Sri
>   Ramashalaka Prashnavali (राम शलाका प्रश्नावली) are based on the
>   Chopais (couplets) from 'Shri Ram Charit Manas' or "Ramayana" written
>   by poet-saint Tulsidas. Ramayana Prashnavali is used to get answers to
>   your questions, predict the outcome of new endeavors, overcome
>   double-mindedness, resolve doubts and select the right path since
>   Vedic times.

**How does it work:**

> Ramayana Prashnavali is a grid of 15X15 Hindi alphabets.
>       Each square in the grid has one Akshar (Hindi alphabet) from nine Chopais (couplets) of Shri Ram Charit Manas.
>       Seeker has to select a grid with closed eye. The Akshars from every ninth square starting from the selected square are taken and
>   joined in a sequence.
>       This creates one Chopai from "Shri Ram Cahrit Manas".
>       The answer to the question asked is derived from this particular Chopai.

**Things to remember while using the Ramcharitramanas Prashnavali:**

> Keep your mind free from all negative thoughts
>       Ask only one question at a time
>       You must pray to Lord Rama before asking your question
>       Ask questions that are pertinent to you and your life only
>       Do not ask vague questions
>       The Prashnavali only shows you the path to solve your problem
>       You should use the Prashnavali only if you have devotion and complete faith in it
>       The grid is covered with 'OM' image so that you can select the character with open eyes without looking or knowing the character you
>   select.
>       You can click anywhere on the image below.
>       The prediction for your query/question will be based on the square you clicked, hidden behind the OM image.
>       Never use this as a game or for amusement purposes

Questions-How did this concept evolve?Does it have any basis in any of our Scriptures?