# Where does Rama Shlaka Prashnavali work?

Tags: ramayana

Following is the image of Tulasidaskrit Rama Shlaka Prashnavali. You can find it in [RamaCharitaManasa of Tulasidasa](https://archive.org/details/RamcharitmanasGitapress/page/n22). First ask any question in mind and we have to select a box by eyes closed.. the letter which gets selected take that next 5th letter after that n search for the word in the given doha next.. it answers your question

[image]

I just want to know does that really works

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! I've edited your question to reference Ramashlaka. Clarify your question bit. "I just want to know where that really works" seems like opinion based question which is not recommended. Visit [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [ask]

Comment: well what is your question exactly? Also you are talking about Ramacaritramanas or Ramayana? And i don't think Valmiki or Tulasidasa ever created a chart like this.

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17513/does-the-ramacharitamanas-prashnavali-concept-have-any-basis-in-scriptures